# GCP Compute engine terraform no external ipv4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, virtual-machine

I am trying to create gcp compute engine using terraform. We have requirement to make sure external ipv4 to no. In the gcloud sdk we can use --no-address flag. Is there any to make sure instance does not get public ip in terraform.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance Thanks

```
network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like this argument needs to be omitted, if I understood your question: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#access_config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the `access_config` section in `network_interface` block as stated in this [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#access_config)

```
network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.name
    }
```